# React-Native onPress doesn't work, when touch the icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'am using [react-native-element](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements)  to create a [button group](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html), that embedded an Icon from [react-native-vector-icons](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) .

the problem is that when the icon is touched, onPress does not get triggered

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
      this.state = { selectedIndex: 0 };   
      this.SetSelected = this.SetSelected.bind(this);
    }


    SetSelected(index) {
      this.setState({ selectedIndex: index });
    }

    return(
    <ButtonGroup
      selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
      onPress={this.SetSelected}
      selectedButtonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
      buttons={[
        {
          element: () => (
            <Icon.Button
              name="slack"
              style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              color={'black'}
              size={30}
              title="Inbox"
            >
              <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 15, textAlignVertical: 'center', textAlign: 'center' }}                   
              >
                All
              </Text>
            </Icon.Button>
          ),
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thanks to Kyle Roach](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1631#issuecomment-443661876),

the reason is 
because I am using an `Icon.Button` which is touchable. So when I try to tap to change the ButtonGroup, the touch event will be caught by `Icon.Button` instead of the button for the `buttonGroup`.

I should use `Icon` instead of `Icon.Button`.

Answer (score 1):

Try making it a function.

```
onPress={() => {this.SetSelected()}}
```

If it doesn't work please provide the this.SetSelected function.